# Cómo buscar en un select de bootstrap una consulta sql con where en php mvc

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap, modal

tengo el siguiente escenario.

Tengo un MODAL para ingreso de datos, como se ve en la imagen.
[image: modal ingreso de datos]

Se observa que tiene dos select uno para codigo de crédito y otro para asesor jurídico.
En esos dos select tengo la clase de boostrap que me sirve para buscar dentro del select una vez se carguen los datos.

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <label>Asesor Juridico <span
                                                                        class="text-danger">*</span></label>
  <select data-placeholder="Seleccione Asesor/a Juridico..." id="cbAsejuridico" name="cbAsejuridico" class="select-search" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();">
    <?php

$filas = $objJuridico->Listar_Juridico();
      if (is_array($filas) || is_object($filas)) {
          foreach ($filas as $row => $column) {
              ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $column['idasejuridico']; ?>">
        <?php echo $column['nombre_asejuridico']; ?>
      </option>
      <?php
          }
      } ?>
  </select>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Mi consulta es:

```
SELECT idasejuridico,codigo_asejuridico,nombre_asejuridico,colegiado,telefono,Direccion,estado FROM crediguate.dbo.asejuridico;
```

LA CONSULTA QUE TENGO ES:
Como puedo hacer para no cargar toda la DATA de la tabla que consulta para mostrar en el select y me permita buscar unicamente algo especifico y luego me devuelva los datos, dentro del: class="select-search"

lo que quiero es agregarle el where a mi consulta y poder buscar dentro del class="select-search"

```
SELECT idasejuridico,codigo_asejuridico,nombre_asejuridico,colegiado,telefono,Direccion,estado FROM crediguate.dbo.asejuridico where nombre_asejuridico=?;
```

Alguna idea, de poder realizarlo, no se si me di a tender.

Comment: Si entiendo bien buscas una consulta de acuerdo a lo que escriba el usuario? de ser asi debes usar autocomplete, puede ser con Jquery directamente o puedes usar plugins como easyautocomplete

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, tratare de documentarme con las sugerencias.

Comment: Dale doy por entendido que esa era tu consulta, si necesitas ayuda avisa y te coloco unos ejemplos

Comment: Claro si me pudieras orientar, con ejemplos, siempre agradecido

Comment: Te deje un ejemplo de Jquery y el link a una libreria que tambien es fácil de manejar

Answer (score 1):

Es sencillo con Jquery:

Cambias tu select por un input

```
<input type="text" id="asesores">
```

y con jQuery Armas tu consulta

```
$("#asesores").autocomplete({
            source:function(request,response){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "consulta_ajax.php",
                    type:"GET",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data:{
                        search: request.term
                    },                    
                    success:function(data){
                        response($data)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
```

y en PHP manejas algo asi:

```
<?php  
  $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST,USER,CLAVE,BASEDATOS);
  $texto = $_GET['term'];
  $sql = " SELECT nombre_usuario FROM mitabla WHERE nombre LIKE '%$texto%' "; 
  $result = $mysqli->query($conexion, $sql);

  while ($myrow = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      $resultado[]=$myrow;
  }

  echo json_encode($resultado);
  ?>
```

Asi tendrías un Input con tus datos de acuerdo a lo que escribas.

---

EDIT:

Si no te Gusta usar Jquery puedes irte por librerias como
http://easyautocomplete.com/

que son buenas y fáciles y a veces algo más estéticas, hay muchas, todo es cuestión de la que más se adapte a ti

Comment: Muchas gracias por la sugerencia y el aporte, me genera mucho valor. Saludos

Comment: Buena respuesta. Tener en cuenta que "easyautocomplete" usa jQuery. Para Vanilla JS, podrías revisar [autComplete.js](https://tarekraafat.github.io/autoComplete.js/#/)